# Scheduled Tasks - Win 2003 - Issues and further explanation of MS/KB

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

Thsi page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308558
claims the following:

> Note Administrators or users with administrator permissions can
>   configure the Task Scheduler to send a
>   notification when a scheduled task
>   does not run as you set it to run. To
>   do so, click Notify Me of Missed Tasks
>   on the Advanced menu.

It also says:

> You can view the log from the
>   Scheduled Tasks window by clicking
>   View Log on the Advanced menu.

I can't find what screen they are talking about.  From control panel, I can click "Schedule Tasks" then "Add a scheduled task" or can click any of the tasks that I have already scheduled.

I'm running a Win2003-SP2 hosted/dedicated server.

I just found the handy command "schtasks" from the command prompt. It's showing me the status of "could not start" on three of my tasks.  I just reset the password on one of them to see if that was the problem.  I haven't really been monitoring them because I didn't believe any changes were made on this server.

Thanks,

Neal Walters

**Update:**

found the schedlgu.txt file:

"SEORank.job" (cscript) 1/9/2010 5:46:00 AM ** ERROR **
    The attempt to retrieve account information for the specified task failed; therefore, the task did not run. Either an error occurred, or no account information existed for the task.
    The specific error is:
    0x8004130f: No account information could be found in the Task Scheduler security database for the task indicated.

Will see if tomorrow this task runs, but would still like more info about what Microsfot KB was talking about.  Is there a nicer interface that I'm missing?

**Update 2** - 
Like I said twice already:

http://cmstrainingvideos.com/images/ForumPosts/ControlpanelWin2003.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Scheduled Tasks window, select the Advanced menu from the menu bar. You should see the items referenced in the article.

Comment: Apparently Win 2003 is different.  I dont' see what this guy shows here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015702/alternative-for-windows-task-scheduler 

That was perhaps my question: What "scheduled task window"? 
Like I said, from control panel - I can click "Schedule a new task" or click on one of the already scheduled tasks.

Comment: You're missing it. Go into Control Panel and open up Sheduled Tasks (double click the Scheduled Tasks item in Control Panel). Once you've got the Scheduled Tasks window open you can select the Advanced Menu.

Comment: See update 2 in original post - what the heck are you talking about? Different version of Windows maybe? At home I have Win 7 - and I have a tool in Admin-Tools. But Win2003 is what you see above. (By the way - double click on "Scheduled Tasks" doesn't do anything).

Comment: @Neal: The problem is in the way you're trying to access the scheduled tasks from the Control Panel. You've got your Start Menu set to expand the Control Panel menu item so it winds up looking like your screen shot. With your mouse on the Control Panel menu item, double click Control Panel so it opens up as a window. Alternately, you can right click the Control Panel menu item and select Open from the context menu.

Comment: Thanks, a picture is worth a 1000 words. I went to "start menu", rt-click properties, advanced tab, and under control panel changed "display as menu" to "display as link".  Or - "right click explore" gets me there (instead of double-click).  I was expecting some special utility to pop-up, but instead, it looks like a normal win explorer screen - but it now has an "Advanced" menu item.

Comment: When I click "notify me of missed tasks" - what will happen?  How does it notify me?  This is remote computer.  Next time I log on to remote desktop?

Comment: Glad you found it and hopefully you'll get to the bottom of the scheduled task issue.

Comment: From the W2K3 help system: If you enable the Notify Me of Missed Tasks setting, the missed tasks dialog box displays at the foreground of the computer display, in front of the logon screen, when there are missed tasks to report. Anyone who sits at the computer can view the list of missed tasks.